# ASP.MVC ajax call information next to dropdown selection

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown from where I pick some things. I'd like to add some information next to each thing from the dropdown so that the user decide which element to pick considering their description.

This is how my dropdown looks like:

```
 <tr>
            <td>@Html.Label("AdminLevel", "Level:")</td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownList("AdminLevel")
                <span id="AdminLevelDescription"></span>
            </td>
 </tr>
```

When I hover on an AdminLevel from the dropdown, for that AdminLevel I would like to display the result of a query that I make on my database, to show all the permissions for that AdminLevel. How could I do this using ajax and javascript? Thank you!

Comment: It depends on how quickly can you get Ajax response from your server. If you think your user can wait dropdown opened and does not hover on another item, until response come back ,then on Ajax success call back try appending result text to dropdown item. Also make sure while appending the item to dropdown it does not gets closed.

Comment: I believe users will never expect that hovering a drop down list item will give them more info. What if the user is using the keyboard to change the selected item? This is just not the default behavior for it. Perhaps using a ListBox (Description appended to the text) instead of a DDL?

Comment: Yes, I've changed my mind, I think that I will display some information next to the dropdown, after the selection is made. Thank you!